# Spatially explicit model to test effects of multiple variables

Tags: modeling, spatial, ecology

What is the appropriate model to test the effects of location, species, and size on tree growth?  So I have both categorical and continuous variables I want in the model.  The following graphic just shows a single plot measured in two consecutive time periods, each point scaled by its size and colored by species.  I want to model the change tree (point) size as a function of neighbor size, distance, species, and initial size.

[image]

Thanks!